# How to show that a partial function is recursive?

Tags: computability, logic, recursion, primitive-recursion

I try to prove that this function is recursive:
$$f(x_1,x_2)= \begin{cases}
2x_1-x_2  & \text{if $x_1 \geqslant \sqrt{x_2}$} \newline
\bot & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

I think that I need to use minimization operator but I don't know how to do that. $\qquad $ $\qquad $ $\qquad$  Maybe i have to prove that 
$$\mu y(|x_1-\sqrt{x_2}| = 0)$$ ?

Comment: $x_1 \geq \sqrt{x_2}$ is equivalent to $x_1^2 \geq x_2$, which should make things easier.

Comment: So I have to use minimisation on $|x_1^2-x_2|=0$?

Comment: Or maybe i have to demonstrate that the predicate $isZero(x_1^2 \dot{-} x_2)$ is recursive and than i need to use minimization operator as $g=\lambda x_2 (isZero(x_1^2 \dot{-} x_2))$ and after doing product between $2x_1-x_2$ and g?

Comment: * $isZero(x_2 \dot{-} x_1^2)$

Comment: What's wrong with implementing the function in Python, C or Haskell? That'll prove it's recursive.

Comment: i can just use just basic primitive function, composition, primitive recursion and minimization. It's from an exam of my university course of some years ago...